# How long will express session last by default

Tags: node.js, express, express-session

I want to know how long will express session last by default, i specified a session.cookie.maxAge for when remember me checkbox is enabled and it works fine, but the default value (when maxAge and expires aren't defined) is lasting forever even if i close the browser.

From Expressjs documentation :

> cookie.expires Specifies the Date object to be the value for the
> Expires Set-Cookie attribute. **By default, no expiration is set**, and
> most clients will consider this a **“non-persistent cookie”** and will
> delete it on a condition like **exiting a web browser application.**
>
> Note If both expires and maxAge are set in the options, then the last
> one defined in the object is what is used.
>
> Note The expires option should not be set directly; instead only use
> the maxAge option.

If it's not possible to destroy session on browser close what is the recommended value of maxAge when remember-me is disabled ?

Comment: until browser tab  closed

Answer (score 1):

Totally depends on the nature of your application.

- Applications of banking-nature won't keep it more than 15 minutes for security reasons.
- Applications otherwise keep them until days, example Gmail, Facebook. Ofcourse, most of them have now migrated to JWT (JSON Web Tokens)

Answer (score 0):

> I want to know how long will express session last by default

if you create a session on the default memoryStore, then it will be deleted when the server restarts

if you are storing the session in a different store/database, then look the package documentation which you used to connect your store. e.g. storing session data to mongoDB using `connect-mongo`, stores the session for 14 days (by default) when you don't specify a expiry time.

> but the default value (when maxAge and expires aren't defined) is lasting forever even if i close the browser.

if you don't specify a expiry time then the sessionId cookie (that is stored in user's browser) will be deleted when user exits the browser. but the session created on the (default) store will persist until the server restarts.

**note:** if user cookie is not being deleted after exiting the browser, then user must have turned on the **"continue where you left off"** option on the (chrome) browser setting

> If it's not possible to destroy session on browser close what is the recommended value of maxAge when remember-me is disabled ?

if "remember-me" is disabled, then don't create a session for that user or delete the created session (ex: `req.session.cookie.maxAge = 86400000`) for that user after some time or set the `rolling` option (in session) to `true`, so that user's cookie expiry time gets updated to the session expiry time